# Trying to add a datatable to a DataSet

Tags: asp.net, dataset

I'm trying to update an existing DataSet with a new table (programatically created, not from a DB).  The minute I do **anything** with the DataSet, whether it's add a table, or move a table somewhere else on the designer, or literally *anything* that makes it be flagged as "unsaved" the application fails to build and gives 100+ errors in "DataSet1.xsd" (but the file is `DataSet.xsd` without the "1") that say such-and-such method is already declared in the class, which is it in the *real* class, not this DataSet1.xsd class that is coming out of nowhere.  The only way for me to fix it is to actually go into my VCS and revert the file; just doing an Undo won't fix it and it'll still throw these errors, but after a revert it will compile and run correctly although I haven't changed anything!

What am I doing wrong here?  The errors are being thrown in this "DataSet1.xsd" class but the actual file is just "DataSet.xsd"

I've done a Clean/Rebuild but to no avail.  I haven't used DataSets in ages so I forget if there's some quirk here I need to do...

EDIT: So I've discovered that making a change to DataSet.xsd creates DataSet1.Designer.cs which causes errors, and deleting that file fixes the errors without, it seems, affecting my changes.  However, although the tables I add manually appear on the dataset designer, they aren't put into the code and I'm unable to access them programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real answer, however:

The whole dataset paradigm was, IMHO, a bad implementation of a bad design.

Some interesting reading:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210125132705/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050405-1.aspx
and it's follow up:
https://web.archive.org/web/20210125131938/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051805-1.aspx

and a good discussion here on SO:
[Why do we still use DataSets in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552371/why-do-we-still-use-datasets-in-net)

Comment: Agreed, but it's existing code so don't have much choice.  What I did figure out is I can copy the contents of DataSet1.xsd (which DOES add the stuff I put on the designer) and then delete it, and it compiles again.  Strange.

Comment: @Allan: Lovely.  Do you have all of the visual studio service packs applied?  I remember running into this exact problem years gone past.  I spent a day trying to get it to work right before I ripped out all dataset.xsd related code.  Fortunately the project was small enough I could do so in a reasonable amount of time.  You would hope they would have fixed it by now.